# can I open .cmb file with php?

Tags: php

> .cmb (database file?) - maybe a product of Chromeleon software.

I need to know if anybody here has an idea about `.cmb` file.
I want to query its data. It is very messy in ms excel. I want o pull data with just a click.
or anybody here know a software that uses a `.cmb` for database.

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find any PHP extensions or libraries to manipulate Chromeleon database files as Chromeleon does not seem to be something that's very common in web programming.

You mentioned that you can export the file to excel.

You can use PHPExcel to open the excel file and manipulate the data: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

Alternatively, export the file as a CSV from excel and then just open the file using PHP and parse it into memory to manipulate.

Comment: Yeah your right, thats my only option. ^_^ thanks. can i ask a point from you? I really want to upvote, but it requires 15.

Comment: If this answer has helped you, you can also accept it to gain a few more points. In the meantime, I have given your question an upvote as other people may be interested in opening non standard formats with PHP.

Comment: thanks friend. I really appreciate your help. ^_^ 'till next problem.